# GCC 5.2 on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: gcc

Can someone walk me through getting the latest version of gcc on Ubuntu 15.04?
I have tried finding testchains but those only go up to 5.1, I believe. Is this something I need wily for?

Comment: please refer [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/gcc.html) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2289994)

Answer (score 4):

1. Install a helpful tool `checkinstall`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install checkinstall
   ```
2. Download the source package [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/), e.g.

   ```
   cd
   wget ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/unix/languages/gcc/releases/gcc-5.2.0/gcc-5.2.0.tar.bz2
   ```
3. Extract the archive

   ```
   tar xf gcc-5.2.0.tar.bz2
   ```
4. Install some development packages

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev 
   sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev
   sudo apt-get install libmpc-dev
   ```
5. Go into the source folder

   ```
   cd gcc-5.2.0
   ```
6. Configure, in my example a 64-bit-only compiler (`--disable-multilib`), for 32-bit and 64-bit support use `--enable-multilib`

   ```
   ./configure --disable-multilib
   ```
7. Start the compiler and drink a coffee or two **;)** This step takes some time.

   ```
   make
   ```
8. Install

   ```
   sudo checkinstall
   ```

   You could also use `sudo make install`, but with `checkinstall` you will have an installed deb package.

Comment: When running these script, with `--enable-multilib` I got `/usr/include/features.h:374:25: fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.' I think one needs to install something like 
 libx32gcc-4.8-dev but for GCC 5.2. I was wondering whether you had any info on this (the ones I find are for older versions of GCC so I don't know if they are still current or if the package names have changed). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2413 The packages of missing files can always found here http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=sys%2Fcdefs.h&mode=&suite=trusty&arch=any I would say, its `libc6-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Download the script on [this](https://gist.github.com/maxlevesque/5813df2fcee107c757f4) page.

Extract the script from the ZIP package and make it executable by entering `chmod +x howto-gcc-5.2-ubuntu15.04.sh` into the terminal.

Run it with `sudo ./howto-gcc-5.2-ubuntu15.04`.

And you will now have GCC 5.2 installed on your system.