# apt-get upgrade fail for Unmet dependencies after gcc compile

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dependencies, gcc

On my headless Ubuntu 14.04.3, I need to use the last release of gcc compiler (version 5.2.0), so I recompiled locally gcc downloading source an doing a checkinstall (thanks to helpful answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/681682/450735)).

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 5.2.0
```

Now, If I run a `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get this error:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these. 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
build-essential : Depends: gcc (>= 4:4.4.3) but 5.2.0-1 is installed  
g++ : Depends: gcc (>= 4:4.9-1ubuntu7) but 5.2.0-1 is installed 
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I tryied to run `sudo apt-get -f install` with the result to no more found gcc command (?) and I recompiled again...

Any idea to un-broke the dependency issue (I presum a conflict between the local gcc installed package and the remote apt repository ) ?

Comment: please add output of `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: I'm not happy to redo the -f install now , I run the command sudo apt-get -f install that seems "solve" but instead afterward I no more found gcc (something broke, maybe just a path... but recompiling require many hours...)

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you using? also,  if you need /usr/bin/gcc-5 you can install gccgo-5 and when you need to use gcc-5 just call on it explicitly and leave version 4 in place

Comment: As I said in first line I have Ubuntu 14.04.3
I also need almost always to compile with gcc 5.2.0, and I do more need any previous release... (at least I need to use clang++3.5 that need gcc 5.2.0 preinstalled... (?!) but this is another story).

Comment: You could try to tell apt to ignore checking dependencies like shown  here http://serverfault.com/q/250224, though I wouldn't 100% recommend that

Comment: Start `checkinstall` again and try another version number, e.g.  `5:5.2.0-1`

Comment: @A.B. I simply run `sudo checkinstall` (it take a lot of time to run...) may you explain what do you mean with `5:5.2.0-1` ? thx

Comment: After starting `checkinstall` you can change the version number. Use `5:5.2.0-1`

Comment: have you had success?

Comment: I deleted compiled temporary stuff (a lot of GB) so I can't redo checkinstall now :(

Comment: Should this question be closed?